# How to show number of people that have filled out a registration form using forminator plugin in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, registration, elementor

I am using the Forminator plugin in Wordpress to create a section of "challenges" that users can sign up for . In order to sign up to this challenges the users are asked to fill out a registration form that requests some personal information.

My goal now is to be able to show how many people have signed up for the challenge on the website, so essentially a counter that shows how many people have filled out the form, as if it were the amount of people attending an event. Is there any way to do this? I am using Wordpress with the Elementor page editor, and the Forminator plugin for the forms.

[image: challenge page screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the number of registered users by adding the code to your functions.php file

```
// Function to return user count
function custom_user_count() { 
$usercount = count_users();
$result = $usercount['total_users']; 
return $result; 
} 
// Creating a shortcode to display user count
add_shortcode('user_count', 'custom_user_count');
```

And then add the following shortcode to your Elementor block:

```
[user_count]
```

To get the users count only for Forminator plugin, please, use:

```
function get_all_submission_count() {
    ob_start();
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'frmt_form_entry';
    $count_query = "select count(*) from $table_name";
    $count = $wpdb->get_var($count_query);
    return $count;
}
```

**UPD**

To get the Submissions without any registration / database issues, please, use the following snippet:

According to this info:

https://wpmudev.com/forums/topic/show-forminator-form-submission-count-in-the-front-end/

You can download the snippet from here:
https://gist.github.com/wpmudev-sls/f0f3068ae2647cba05911a5374b38447

Once downloaded, you can unzip it and upload the wpmudev-forminator-shortcode-show-submissions.php file to your site’s wp-content/mu-plugins directory.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do I have to create a user database that visitors of our web can sign up to in order to make this work? There isn't a register/login function in the web at the moment, and the plan was not to add one. And where does the Forminator code you added have to be input? also inside the functions.php file?

Comment: @JDom please, check the update in my answer

Comment: Glad to help! Please, feel free to submit my answer as a correct one